# Save value from column to variable

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

How can I save a value from a column to a variable?

My table:

```
+------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id   | hwid | password | force       | created             |   
+------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 0004 |    4 | NULL     |           1 | 2017-10-31 17:28:23 |
+------+------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I want to save the '1' of force in a variable.

Currently I have this:

```
force=$(mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "SELECT force FROM $database_name.settings WHERE hwid = '$hwid'")
```

My result is:

```
forceupdate 1
```

But I only want 1 (or 0) as result.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use "mysql -e", try to use "mysql -Bse"

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
force="${force#* }";echo "$force"
```

Comment: The result is then always empty.

Comment: Perhaps it's tab so try force="${force##*[[:blank:]]}";echo "$force"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the solution. I use the parameter -N:
-N, --skip-column-names
                      Don't write column names in results.